# Facing issue while accessing Navigation Setting link on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting following error while accessing navigation setting link of my sharepoint site:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at ASP.c3d51703_a22c_4668_823e_4093ea1a85c6_2017521888._*Render*_control83(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TemplateBasedControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TemplateBasedControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Please Help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: seems like there is a control on your sharepoint page which is throwing error while rendering, recently made any changes to your site ?

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logs for any other signs of problems leading up to the error?